# Error in an Isabelle function definition taken from lecture notes

Tags: isabelle

Why does the following definition of a function (class)

```
definition nondecreasing_on :: "real set => (real => real) => bool"
where "nondecreasing_on S f <-> (ALL x:S. ALL y:S. x<=y --> f x <= f y)"
```

return `Inner syntax error⌂ Failed to parse prop` ?

This definition is taken from [this](http://dream.inf.ed.ac.uk/projects/isabelle/Isabelle_Primer.pdf) text, linked from the lectures notes section of the Isabelle community wiki, so it should be correct.
(Granted, the text is old, so maybe the syntax has changed, but even after replacing all the `:`'s with `\in`'s to give it a proper LaTeX-like formatting, importing `Complex_Main` instead of `Main` as the lecture notes suggest, removing potentially problematic symbols such as `_` and so on, the error persists.)

Answer (score 1):

You can see in Isabelle/jEdit that the `<` of the `<->` is underlined red. The old ASCII syntax is being removed more and more. In modern Isabelle, the definition would look like this:

```
definition nondecreasing_on :: "real set ⇒ (real ⇒ real) ⇒ bool"
  where "nondecreasing_on S f ⟷ (∀x∈S. ∀y∈S. x ≤ y ⟶ f x ≤ f y)"
```